Description of the mouth in Chovos Halevavos
How does the 'sefer Chovos Halevavos' describe the human mouth and why?- For shmiras halashon info.

What makes you think it does describe the mouth?

https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=mouth&tab=text&tpathFilters=Jewish%20Thought%2FRishonim%2FDuties%20of%20the%20Heart%2FDuties%20of%20the%20Heart&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance

https://www.sefaria.org/Shemirat_HaLashon%2C_Book_I%2C_The_Gate_of_Remembering.8.6?lang=bi&sbsq=%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA&with=SidebarSearch&lang2=en
